# Using alt text with a background image?

Tags: html, css, seo, background-image

For SEO purposes and clean/semantic code could we not use a transparent .png in a  tag with alt text at the same time as a CSS background-image?

Example:

CSS:

```
.ImgClickTrans {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#image-in-question {
    background-image: url(../images/bg-image-5.jpg);
}
```

along with this HTML:

```
<div id="image-in-question">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
        <img class="ImgClickTrans" src="../images/trans.png" alt="EVER IMPORTANT ALT TEXT">
    </a>
</div>
```

Do we know if this is considered cheating (sort of like a text-indent of -9999px) or not?
In my simplistic way of thinking it gives us the best of both worlds. The style we desire with the background image along with crawlable alt text for Google and screenreaders.

I appreciate any input.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Why not just let the image element have the correct source and force the img element to fill the div?

Answer (score 2):

That's not semantic because the words used within an image’s alt attribute should be its text equivalent and convey the same information or serve the same purpose that the image  More on why you should not use any sort of background alt text trick is here: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200905/css_background_images_cannot_and_should_not_have_alternate_text/

Anyway i don't think that now it could be spotted as spam from google, but at least don't fill it up with too many keyword.